# What language does the phonetic inventory of ERA's "Ameno" most resemble?

Tags: phonemes, constructed-language

The [lyrics](https://www.google.com/search?q=ameno+lyrics) of the [1996 song "Ameno" by Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ameno_(song)) are said to be in pseudo-Latin:

> Dori me
> Interimo, adapare
> Dori me
> Ameno Ameno

etc. Indeed, phonotactically (and, in one word — "imperavi" — lexically) it resembles Latin, but the phonetic inventory is smaller. There is no B, S, F, K, G. The list of letters/sounds used in the lyrics, from most to least common, is E M O A R N I D T P V U L.

What natural language has phonetic inventory (not necessarily phonemic, allophones are okay) most resembling that one?

Comment: The lyrics contain no more than a few dozen distinct words to begin with, so there’s not really much of a reason to expect that the entire phonetic inventory should be represented. It could be pure coincidence that there’s no s or k, for example. For comparison, note that this entire comment is completely devoid (by accident, as it happens, not intentionally) of /dʒ/ <j, g>, despite that being a perfectly common sound in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's  why I've asked not for the exact match but the closest match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are phoneme inventories that can be downloaded as a whole or searched. Full absence of velar consonants is a rare feature of natural languages.

Doing a search on [UPSID](http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/upsid_find.html) for languages without any velar consonant (absence of G, K, NG) I found only two languages, [Vanimo](http://menzerath.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/L/L8640.html) from Papua New Guinea and [Klao](http://menzerath.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/L/L4133.html), a Niger-Kordofanian language. Only Vanimo may be kind of a good match, Klao has some rare consonants, including coarticulated kp and gb.

For some better metric of similarity (like using a cosine distance between inventory vectors) you can [download the Phoible database](https://phoible.org/download) and run you own scripts.

Comment: The [Hawaiian phoneme inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language#Phonology) is very close with [k] and [t] being allophones of a single phoneme: “The [t]–[k] variation is quite unusual among the world's languages, and is likely a product both of the small number of consonants in Hawaiian, and the recent shift of historical *t to modern [t]–[k], after historical *k had shifted to [ʔ].”

Comment: @YellowSky In that regard, Tahitian is closer, as [k] is [not even listed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahitian_language#Phonology) as an allophone of [t];

Comment: @LeoB. - Yes, in respect of [k], but Tahitian has [f] which you said is “forbidden”. Besides, Tahitian has no [l], while in Hawaiian [r]~[l] are allophones.

Comment: @YellowSky Well, Vanimo has [s], so one liberty or another has to be taken.

Comment: Hmm, Vanimo (I've worked on one of its close relatives) has nasal vowels, tone, /b/...